# Travelling to US with a US visa with wrong date of birth

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I am Indian citizen who has a valid US B1/B2 visa on my old expired passport. However, this old expired passport has my wrong date of birth and hence the wrong date of birth on my US Visa too. Also, I have traveled to the US once on this old passport. Now, I've rectified the date of birth on my new passport. I will be traveling to United States next month. In order to clear this confusion, I have made an affidavit mentioning the discrepancies. Is there anything else that's needed to make sure I don't have problems at the US immigration when I arrive?

---

### Update:

The affidavit mentions that:

1. My passport before the old passport (my very first passport) had the correct date of birth. I mention the passport no. etc.
2. My other identity documents (birth certificate, PAN card, driver's license) have the correct date of birth.
3. My old passport has the date of birth misplaced by a day, which is incorrect.
4. My new (current) passport has the got the date of birth rectified as per my other identity documents.

I thought of re-applying for the visa. But it does not make sense since I already have the visa approved. It's just that the date of birth is inconsistent with my new passport. This seems more of an amendment that needs to be made to my visa.

Comment: Can you give an update on what you eventually did and what happened? Did you have to get a new visa and/or did you encounter problems when traveling?

Answer (score 7):

**Edit: it is a serious issue **

From what you said it appears that in past you used the document, which you knew had clearly invalid personal data. You presented this document to the US consulate, received the US visa, traveled to US using this document and used it until the expiration date.

Now, when applying for the visa, you had to type in your date of birth. If you typed the invalid one matching the passport (which is most likely scenario, as otherwise either your visa would have the correct DOB, or you'd be told to get a fixed passport), this may be interpreted as "committing fraud by misrepresentation to obtain visa". Not only this will likely prevent you from getting more visas, but this is a criminal offense in the US.

This is very different from the case when an issued visa had a typo (i.e. you provided correct information, but it wasn't transferred to the visa), or the case when the information was correct at the moment you applied for the visa, but changed later (such as if you legally changed your name or DOB).

So if you used this document with invalid information until it expired, and if you also typed the invalid date of birth into your visa application, it would be quite hard to convince the Consulate that you made a honest mistake, and overlooked this. Please note that your affidavit and the evidence you're going to present basically would prove that you **knowingly** provided false information on a visa application.

Thus I suggest you talk to a qualified lawyer about this all, and follow his/her advice.

---

The old answer is below, but it doesn't seem to apply to your case, because it considers circumstantial changes (such as if your date of birth was officially changed by the court order during this time), and this is not your case.

Most likely you'd need to get a new visa. Department of State doesn't address the situation with the change of birthdate, but [it does address the situation with a name change](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html) (which is obviously more common):

> I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?
>
> **If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.**

In your case it is even worse, because it is unclear to others which passport has the valid date of birth. You know the new passport has it right, but the airline or immigration officials might assume the old passport had it right, and the new one has a mistake - and they have no obligation to consider your other documents.

Comment: Given how common it is in India for _official_ documents to have wrong information, and how difficult it can be for these documents to be corrected, I would not automatically consider use of such a document fraudulent. The embassy and consulates are certainly aware of these issues.

Answer (score 3):

Since now on your 'current' passport has your correct DOB, the information should be the same on your visa as well.

I agree that you have an affidavit supporting that the DOB was misprinted on the previous passport but the affidavit is solely reliant on the discretion of the immigration officer. Officially speaking the visa should have the same personal details as on your current passport.

I would suggest you follow the instructions of the nearest embassy.

> If you think your visa was printed incorrectly and your visa interview
>   took place at the U.S. Embassy, New Delhi, please email
>   support-india@ustraveldocs.com and explain why you think there is an
>   error.  If necessary, we will provide instructions on how to submit
>   your passport.

If the embassy supports your affidavit then viola your issue would be solved, otherwise do as instructed. I would strongly suggest to not travel without consulting the embassy.

PS : Would be interested in an update after your comm with the embassy.

EDIT : As George pointed out, you may want to prepare an explanation that why didn't you correct the DOB on the previous passport straightaway. why did you travel on it etc.

Comment: I would also add an explanation why he traveled for (five? ten?) years with the old passport which he knew had the incorrect date of birth, instead of returning it to the passport office and ask to correct the mistake. Consulate might indeed ask about that.

Comment: Those instructions seem more intended for someone who has just received their visa and finds it has a typo or other error, not someone who has had a visa for some time and their information has changed. You could certainly try contacting them with that email and asking, but I would expect the procedure to be different.

Comment: definitely the correction should've been made on the passport years ago. and technically the visa wasn't misprinted; and, in most cases the only changeable personal detail is the Name (Date of issue/expire are bound to change automatically). There is like absolutely no clause which handles wrong information on a passport; so I provided the next best way out for the OP. I personally expect the embassy would deny a misprint/mistake on the visa and ask to reapply