US Visa with Wrong Date of Birth
I am Indian citizen who has a valid US B1/B2 visa on my old expired passport. However, this old expired passport has my wrong date of birth and hence the wrong date of birth on my US Visa too. Also, I have traveled to the US once on this old passport. Now, I've rectified the date of birth on my new passport. I plan to travel to United States at the end of the year. Do I need to re-apply for a new B1/B2 visa? Is there any other solution?

I’d imagine you have two options in this scenario: 1. Travel with both passports and evidence to prove the legal change to your date of birth; 2. Apply for a new visa. I know which one I’d choose, but then I am very risk averse with regard to visas/immigration etc

Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76695/travelling-to-us-with-a-us-visa-with-wrong-date-of-birth - is this a common problem for Indians travelling to the USA?

@henry - this is not a common problem

What was done to "rectify the date of birth" on your new passport? Is there evidence to prove a legal change to your date of birth? If so, what is that evidence?
